# Deploying Artful Aardvark 17.10 with MaaS 2.2 fails to bring-up networking

Tags: networking, server, maas, 17.10

I'm running MaaS 2.2.2 and trying to deploy Artful on my systems. This system currently deploys Xenial without issues. The systems PXE boot from MaaS, proceed to successfully deploy the image, but upon reboot the systems get stuck on bringing up networking. At "Started Network Service." the system hangs for a few minutes and then does not get an IP to my primary NIC (from which it deployed). Over serial console I can log in and bring up the networking interface manually and then it works fine. I also confirmed this on several different systems with different brand NICs so it doesn't appear to be a driver issue. Is this a known issue or has something changed in config going to Artful?

Answer (score 0):

[1] Ubuntu 17.10 Server uses netplan & networkd to configure networking. ifupdown and e.g. /etc/network/interfaces are no longer used. Is your MAAS setup compatible with these changes?

Check out your new config file /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml

This is the default netplan config file /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml which does DHCP:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# For more information, see netplan(5).
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    ens3:
      dhcp4: yes
      dhcp6: yes
```

This is a working config /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml for a static IPV4 address (IPV6 not used, but not disabled):

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# For more information, see netplan(5).
##RHMOD
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    ens3:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      #####accept-ra: no
      addresses: [192.168.0.55/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.0.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4]
```

[2] I know of one situation where systemd-networkd waits 2 minutes: if you disable either IPV4 or IPV6 (not both of course). Did you?

It causes a timeout of 2 minutes in the service systemd-networkd-wait-online. 
This is the typical error in the sysylog:

```
> ...Oct 20 01:54:56 myvm systemd-networkd-wait-online[435]: Event loop
> failed: Connection timed out
> ...A Start job is running for Wait For
```